# product can have only one taxonomy

Tags: spree

I am working on spree and want to make changes in admin panel as an admin can add only one taxonomy(primary category) and correspondingly add more tertiary categories (taxons) that come from only that taxonomy.
how should i proceed for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow, you want to have max one root taxonomy in admin section. When admin tries to create new one, this action should be blocked. If so it can be done on different ways. I would try this:

- block creating new taxon if there are already taxon in database - override Spree Taxon model, you might use before_create callback and check if root taxon is in DB and block creation.
- in templates you can override admin taxon index and hide add taxon button if there is a taxon already

Comment: the only issue i am having at this point is of the select2 in admin panel it doesnot work properly if i make changes or even if I write the same code using deface.

Comment: also as many taxons can be created in the db once a root taxonomy has been selected you can no more choose another root taxonomy from the select2 dropdown now you can choose 4 sub categories(taxons) from that choosen root taxonomy

Comment: It's hard to predict how you made changes in SPree to achive your goal. You need to show more.

Comment: i still have not made any changes all changes have been reverted as i cannot get through the checks at taxons and ancestors which invokes a callback